# What will happen if a field doesn't have a finite extension of degree n?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Suppose $K$ is a field, $n$ is a positive integer.

1.If $K$ doesn't have a finite extension of degree n, can we get some good properties of $K$?

2.Can it happen if $K$ has extensions of degree $n-1$ and $n+1$ but doesn't have an extension of degree $n$?

3.What if we change the condition to: $K$ doesn't have a finite extension of degree larger than $n$? Can we prove that any extension of $K$ of degree $n$ must be its algebraic closure? Hence $n$ must be $2$ by Artin-Schreier theorem.

Well, some easy examples are: $\mathbb Q$, any finite field $F$ and $\mathbb R$, and it's well-known that $\mathbb Q$ and $F$ have finite extensions of each positive degree, but $\mathbb R$ just have an extension of degree $2$.

Comment: For 2: look at $\bigcup_{m\ge 1}\Bbb{F}_{2^m}$ and $n$ even. For 3: $\overline{K}=\bigcup_{m\ge 1} K_m$ where $K_m\subset K_{m+1}$ so $[\overline{K}:K]=\sup_{F/K} [F:K]$.

Comment: Sorry I meant $\bigcup_{m\ge 1}\Bbb{F}_{\textstyle 2^{2^m}}$

Comment: @reuns Thank you for your examples. For your second example, do you mean that $K_m$=$\mathbb Z_{3^{3^m}}$ (just like the first example)?

Comment: For an arbitrary field then $[\overline{K}:K]=\sup_{[F:K] \ finite} [F:K]$

Comment: @reuns Thank you very much!